# in WPForms plugin, can we add user journey with abandonment forms?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, wpforms

I am using WPForms pro plugin. I have also installed User Journey and Abandonment Form addons, now I want to add user journey to abandonment forms, Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I tried google but did not find a solution that's why I am here to ask.

Answer (score 0):

User Journey starts tracking all the data right after the add-on activation. You don't need to do anything anywhere.
The data is displayed in a table on a single-entry page in the admin area.